# How to get id of selected option in dropdown?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to get the id of selected option in dropdown.

I have a dropdow that displays company names from database. Now I want get the id of that company. How do i do that?

```
<select required name="org-list" id="org-list" class="form-control">    
    <option value="">Select</option>    
    <?php foreach($org as $value) { ?>              
        <option id="org"  value="<?php echo $value['org_name'];?>"><?php echo $value['org_name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**The Model**

```
public function get_organisation()
{
    $q = $this->db->select('*') 
        ->from('company') 
        ->get(); 
    return $q->result_array(); 
}
```

And in my controller i want the id of selected option from database.

```
$data = $this->key_m->array_from_post(array('id','org-list','keys'));
$data['keys'] = $license;
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: What is the use of `value` if you use `id`?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves  in my views i want to print the company names in dropdown but in my controller want to get the id of that company

Comment: Your question is not unclear. If u want to just want id from drop down . Use jquery. If you want to pass that value to server , use ajax or post the form back to server .

Comment: @WaiYanHein I think ajax can help me here but i dont know how do i use here can u please help

Comment: You got the answer already ?

Comment: @WaiYanHein yes i have but i would like to learn if you can show me the ajax way

Comment: I just posted an answer for ajax using jquery.

Comment: Please up the answer if it is useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the organization id in option tag's value.  like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $value['org_id'];?>"><?php echo $value['org_name']; ?></option>
```

No need to provide id attribute to each option tag. When you will submit the form value of "org-list" will be selected organization id.

Comment: i am not getting id in my controller :( when i var_dump i get id = FALSE

Comment: and what value of 'org-list' you are getting ?

Comment: I am getting this : that i organization name 'org-list' => string 'Bizrtc' (length=6)

Comment: i do like this $data = $this->key_m->array_from_post(array('id','org-list','keys'));
    $data['keys'] = $license;
    var_dump($data);

Comment: If you applied as I suggested , just check with print_r($_REQUEST); in your controller ? and check the value of $_REQUEST['org-list']

Comment: i get this: Array ( [/admin/key] => [org-list] => 1 [keys] => 10 )

Comment: but why dont i get it in my id?

Comment: See I want to print the Company names in my dropdown, but i want to get the id in my POST which company i select

Comment: I have given the solution for the same dear :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102428/discussion-between-rajan-and-learningmode).

Comment: Undefined Index org_id

Comment: in your code _foreach($org as $value)_ what is organization id name in $org ? Is it just 'id' or 'org_id' or what ?

Comment: its just id in my organization table its just id normal primary key

Comment: ok then use _$value['id']_ instead of _$value['org_id']_ in my given ans

Answer (score 2):

This is the ajax way

```
$.post(url,{ id : "id value from drop down here" },function(data){
    //This is the call back for success
})
```

For that one, you need jquery. The is the easiest way to use. Url is where you are posting back to server.

> In your server side catch like this

```
$this->input->post('id')
```

Because you used "id" in the ajax request. So you have to retrieve it using the field name 'id' . Hope you get it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things which you "should" / "could" change. At first I noticed that your ID attribute is "org", Id's are supposed to be unique and yours is not. Though, back to the actual question. You should change your code as follow:

```
<select required  name="org-list"  id="org-list" class="form-control">  
    <option value="">Select</option>    
      <?php foreach($org as $value): ?>              
           <option id="<?php echo $value['org_id'];?>"  value="<?php echo $value['org_id'];?>"><?php echo $value['org_name']; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Now in your controller you grab the selected ID like: `$this->input->post('org-list')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide value for each `id` attr. for corresponding `<option>`

```
<select required  name="org-list"  id="org-list" class="form-control">  
   <option value="">Select</option>    
     <?php foreach($org as $value): ?>              
         <option id="<?php echo $value['org_id'];?>"  value="<?php echo $value['org_name'];?>"><?php echo $value['org_name']; ?></option>
     <?php endforech; ?>
</select>
```